# Spring boot test does not initialize application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I followed a standard spring boot tutorial for restful web services and wanted to add a test

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class DQApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    DQService service;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        Assertions.assertThat(service).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

but I'm getting the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext"

The application itself runs just fine with zero configuration (no xml files, just an app class annotated with @SpringBootApplication. IntelliJ IDEA warns me about @Autowired being "not defined in a valid bean" but suggests no fix

how do i fix the test?

Comment: please share complete stacktrace that you see in console.

Comment: It fails to load the context, the stacktrace will give you the reason. I suggest to read it.